# Error while using setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in FadingActionBarHelper

Tags: android

I want to implement `FadingActionBar` in my application `to get the effects like latest Google play Music app.`
Below is how i am using the FadingActionBar

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
            .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
            .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
            .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_listview);
        setContentView(helper.createView(this));
        helper.initActionBar(this);
```

Here i wanted to add back button in actionBar using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
I am getting error while adding the above code saying no such method found.

My question is there any way to add `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
if not, how we can add back button for `FadingActionBar`

Comment: You can add this method in [`FadingActionBarHelperBase.java`](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar/blob/master/library/src/com/manuelpeinado/fadingactionbar/FadingActionBarHelperBase.java)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but it was because i was using appcompat v7 so you just have to add this.

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Or

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps